# access deined error when using boto3 inside lambda function to trigger mediaConvert job from s3 upload trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-media-convert

I have an s3 bucket.

when a file is uploaded to that bucket a s3 trigger is fired which triggers a lambda function which using boto3 works to create a job in Media Convert with the file that caused the trigger. However I am getting a

`AccessDeniedException`

```
[ERROR] ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateJob operation: User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx:assumed-role/reads3MODRole/sendUploadedFileToMediaConvert is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:role/service-role/MediaConvert_Default_Role
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 119, in lambda_handler
    "contentpostid": contentpostid
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

the error states that one role is not authorized to perform iam:PassRole on resource on another.

I went through IAM to try and add that role but I was not able to find it to attach to the policy.

my lambda code is as follows with most of it omited only the boto3 function is shown:

```
# Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
    contentype = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['content-type']
    userid = response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-meta-user']
    contentpostid =response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPHeaders']['x-amz-meta-contentpost']
    client = boto3.client('mediaconvert')
    response = client.create_job(
      Settings={
    "OutputGroups": [
      {
        "Name": "CMAF",
        "Outputs": [ // obmitted.
```

Im not sure how to resolve this.

[image]

Comment: What is your lambda execution role?

Comment: added a screen to the question

Comment: The error msg indicates that `sendUploadedFileToMediaConvert` role has no such permissions. But your screenshots show that your lambda role has different name. Can you please clarify what are these roles?